# Custom code doesn't work

Tags: javascript

i tried to add some code to my theme, following this:
[How do I include JavaScript on a single page in a way that is amenable to scale](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215010/how-do-i-include-javascript-on-a-single-page-in-a-way-that-is-amenable-to-scale)

i created my js file in:
C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-8.7.2\themes\bootstrap\js

i put this  on the file:

```
        (function ($) {
         Drupal.behaviors.[myName] =  {
        attach: function(context, settings) {

          //Begin my code
          alert("'.$phpvariable.'");
         //I'm done with my code

        }
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

so i opened the file bootstrap.libraries.yml and putted this:

```
my-library:
  js: 
    js/my-script.js: {}
```

after that i put on the file bootstrap.info.yml this:

```
type: theme
base theme: false

name: 'Bootstrap'
description: 'Built to use Bootstrap, a sleek, intuitive, and powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development.'
package: 'Bootstrap'


core: 8.x
libraries: 
 - my-theme/global-effects
 - bootstrap/js/my-library
```

now...nothing work and i not understand why....can anyone help me?

Comment: It would help if you showed us the complete script, your current theme.libraries.yml and theme.info.yml. (Also how you are including the js in the appropriate templates/pages.) BTW this `my-library: js: js/my-script.js: {}` is not proper YML. Formatting is important.

Comment: What is `alert("'.$phpvariable.'");` supposed to do? You can't print server side PHP variables in client side JavaScript code.

Comment: just open a popup.

what i am doing wrong? please help me

Comment: Your .info should be `bootstrap/my-library`. You should readup on using a base theme. You don't want to alter bootstrap theme directly because when you update the bootsrap theme you'll lose your changes. The corect way is to create a custom theme and use bootstrap as your base theme.

Comment: keep it simple `alert('Hello World');` get this working first.

Comment: i tried with everythink you telled me but nothing works :(

Answer (score 1):

There are a few items worth mentioning here.

- The first is that you'll want to avoid making modifications to existing modules and themes. For your use case, it would be better to create a new theme of your own and use Bootstrap as the base theme.
  Here is a good link to get you started: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme. Bootstrap is somewhat advanced, so it might be better to practice first using Classy as your base theme.
- As sdmeyers pointed out, YAML formatting is very important. If you have a script named `my-script.js` that lives in the `/js` folder in your theme, then your libraries YAML file will look like this:

```
my_module.my_cool_library:
  js:
    js/my-script.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Take note also of the dependencies, which are necessary in order to use Drupal behaviors. Also note that, in YAML files, every indent is exactly 2 spaces (and no tabs!).

- As Hudri pointed out, you can't pass variables directly from PHP to Javascript. Instead, you'll want to use `drupalSettings`. Here are some links to help you understand:

  - https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module
  - https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview
  - https://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/javascript/behaviors.html

For your use case, your PHP would look like this:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_module.my_cool_library';
$form['#attached']['drupalSettings']['my_module'] = [
  'print_this' => 'Hello World!',
];
```

And your JS would look like this:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.my_module = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('body').once('my-module').each(function () {
        const print_me = settings.my_module.print_this;
        alert(print_me);
        // Success!
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

- Any time you make changes to your theme, you'll need to clear your site's cache. You can do so by visiting Configuration > Performance, or from the console with `drush cr` (this requires that [Drush](https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) is installed) or `drupal cache:rebuild all` (this requires that [Drupal Console](https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/getting/composer.html) is installed).

---

I strongly recommend building your own theme in order to practice. A minimal theme only needs a few files. Here's a good step-by-step introduction: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-8-theming-fundamentals-part-1

As for the PHP code, it's a snippet that you would attach to other code. For demonstration's sake, add this hook to your `.theme` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MY_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Attaches this functionality to any form on your site.
  // This probably isn't what you actually want to do, but is a good demonstration.
  // Don't forget to clear your site cache!
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_module.my_cool_library';
  $form['#attached']['drupalSettings']['my_module'] = [
    'print_this' => 'Hello World!',
  ];
}
```

Be sure to change the **MY_THEME** part for the actual name of your theme. So, if your theme is named 'practice', then your hook would be `practice_form_alter()`.

Hooks are an absolutely essentially part of theme building, so be sure to understand how they work: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/hooks/8.7.x

And as always: Don't forget to clear your site cache!

Comment: Hi thank you a lot!
I already read the documentation  but i not really understand where i have to put my php, if i put it in my custom text on my view it just write me the code...

can you please help me?

Comment: thank you, i read AGAIN all the documentation but it still not work.

I created a new atlas theme how described here:

https://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-8-theming-fundamentals-part-1
added all the stuff but it still not work.


Please help me, i am becoming crazy with this

Comment: i have to add the php file in the core.api.php?

Comment: You’re too deep into this and off track. Start simpler by just getting a file to load before jumping into php.

Comment: ok thanks with guide now seems better but my page give me this error


 function atlas_preprocess_page(&$variables) { if ($variables['is_front']) { $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'atlas/fancy-effect'; } }